# Is closure of a semigroup again a semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, semigroups

Let $S$ be a compact left-topological semi-group (meaning, $S$ is both a semi-group and a compact Hausdorff topological space, and the map $x \mapsto x y$ is continuous for any fixed $y$, but the map $y \mapsto xy$ may not be continuous).

Consider $T_0 \subset S$ which is a sub-semigroup, but is not necessarily compact. A rather straightforward application of Kuratowski-Zorn shows that there exists a minimal compact sub-semigroup $T$ of $S$ which contains $T_0$. Wishful thinking suggests that $T = \overline{T}_0$, and this would be right and easy to show, if only multiplication was continuous in both arguments. It would also work under the assumption that $T_0$ is commutative.

I do not believe this is true in general, but I can't see an easy counterexample. Could somebody be so kind as to present one? Of course, if it *is* generally true that $T = \overline{T}_0$, then I would be even happier and more grateful!

Comment: Are there standard examples for $S$ where $y\to xy$ definitely fails to be continuous?

Comment: You don't really need Kuratowski-Zorn for this: just take the intersection of all closed semigroups containing $T_0$.

Comment: The one I know, and the one I am interested in primarily, is the \v{C}ech-Stone compactification of a discrete semigroup like $\mathbb{N}$. However, it is not very easy to get a hold on how things work there.

Comment: @tomasz: That's absolutely right, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Feanor Hm, with this being described as (at least) 'three headed monster', I'm afraid anything could happen and wishful thinking is just that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: That is what I would suspect. What I was hoping for is a more elementary example to give some intuition how this particular piece of wishful thinking fails.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\operatorname{Fun}(X,X)$ be the set of all functions $X \to X$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence. This is easily seen to be a left-topological semigroup (in Feanor's sense), but $g \mapsto fg$ is only continuous if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I've tried searching [topological semigroup closure subsemigroup](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=topological+semigroup+closure+subsemigroup). Found
[Proposition 1.4.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA28) in Arkhangelski, Tkachenko: Topological Groups and Related Structures:
*Let $G$ be a semitopological semigroup, and $H$ a subsemigroup of $G$. Then the closure $\overline H$ of $H$ in $G$ is a (semitopological) subsemigroup of $G$.* Proof is also given there. Example 1.4.11 shows that *Proposition 1.4.10 cannot be extended to right topological semigroups.*

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you, this is precisely the type of example I was looking for!

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Example 1.4.11 is a counterexample to the question (it is compact and Feanor has left/right switched when compared to Arhangel'skii, Tkachenko).

Comment: If you want more details or think that something is missing in my answer, please let me know.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you, it is a complete and great answer; sorry for not accepting it sooner.

Comment: You want $T_0$ to be contained in the topological center of $S$.  The topological center is the subsemigroup of all elements whose left translations are continuous. The closure of any subsemigroup of the topological center is a subsemigroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting the comments to an answer:

1. tomasz points out that we have $$T = \bigcap \{G \mid G \supseteq T_0 \text{ is a closed subsemigroup of }S\} \supseteq \overline{T}_0.$$
2. The semigroup $S = \operatorname{Fun}(X,X)$ of all functions $f \colon X \to X$ on a topological space $X$ is a left-topological semigroup under composition when equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence, i.e., the product topology $X^X$. Observe that $g \mapsto fg$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous, so on a non-discrete $T_1$ space $S$ is not a right topological semigroup.
3. Martin Sleziak remarks that Arhangel'skii-Tkachenko provide the following counterexample in [Topological groups and related structures](http://books.google.com/books?id=hIEnzrOBbW0C&pg=PA28) (example 1.4.11).

   Consider the one-point compactification $X = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ of the natural numbers. Then $S = \operatorname{Fun}(X,X)$ is a compact left-topological semigroup.

   Let $T_0 \subset S$ be the subsemigroup consisting of *injective* functions $X \to X$. The functions $f_k$ defined by $f_k(n) = n+k$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_k(\infty) = \infty$ are in $T_0$ and they converge pointwise to the constant function $f(n) = \infty$, so $f \in \overline{T}_0$.

   Let $g(n) = n+1$ and $g(\infty) = 1$, so $g \in T_0$. We have $g \circ f_k \in T_0$ and $g \circ f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in X$. Since $g \in T_0 \subseteq T$ and $f \in \overline{T}_0 \subseteq T$ we have that $g \circ f \in T$. Now observe that $g \circ f \notin \overline{T}_0$. Indeed, the set $U = \{s \in S \mid s(1) = 1\text{ and } s(123) = 1\}$ is open in $S$ and disjoint from $T_0$, while $g \circ f \in U$, so $g \circ f \in T \setminus \overline{T}_0$.